# Python - Using a functions output to iterate over a command

Tags: python, azure, function, loops

I have written some functions to do the following:

- Get a list of clusters
- Get a list of resource groups, that those clusters reside
- Pass these two lists into another function that will run it iteratively and return the output.

My question is how can I use the outputs of the two functions that retrieve the cluster and resource groups and pass them in as arguments and iterate over the command for each value.

I've tried converting them into strings but this results in using them all in one command.

I'm just very stuck on how to iterate over the list containing the arguments.

Below is a breakdown of the code.

I am using the following packages:

azure.cli.core - get_default_cli
os

az_helper function - this invokes the az cli with the arguments you pass in:

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
import os


def az(args, suppress_stdout=False):
    cli = get_default_cli()

    if suppress_stdout:
        cli.invoke(args, out_file=open(os.devnull, "w"))
    else:
        cli.invoke(args)

    if cli.result.result:
        return cli.result.result
    elif cli.result.error:
        raise cli.result.error

    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    az(args="", suppress_stdout=False)
```

I've then written two functions to collect the resource groups and cluster names:

```
from az_helper import az


# Function to get the cluster names
def get_aks_clusters():
    cli_args = (
        "aks",
        "list",
        "--query",
        "[].name",
        "-o",
        "json"
    )

    clusters = az(cli_args, suppress_stdout=True)

    outputs = []

    for cluster in clusters:
        outputs.append(cluster)
    return outputs


# Function to get cluster resource groups
def get_aks_rg():
    cli_args = (
        "aks",
        "list",
        "--query",
        "[].resourceGroup",
        "-o",
        "json"
    )

    resource_groups = az(cli_args, suppress_stdout=True)

    outputs = []

    for rg, value in enumerate(resource_groups):
        outputs.append(value)
    return outputs
```

This final function is where I want to combine the outputs of the above and pass them in as arguments to be iterated over:

```
# This function will get the latest version running on the AKS cluster
def get_aks_k8s_ver(cluster, rg):

    cli_args = (
        "aks",
        "get-upgrades",
        "-g",
        rg,
        "-n",
        cluster,
        "--query",
        "controlPlaneProfile.kubernetesVersion",
        "-o",
        "json"
    )

    cluster_versions = az(cli_args, suppress_stdout=False)

    return list(cluster_versions)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the output? And what output do you expect?

Comment: The output I would like to expect is when the function `get_aks_k8s_ver` runs, it invokes the AZ command to check the current AKS version running. 

This works when manually inputting the cluster name and resource group but I want to use the two functions that output the resource group and cluster names and add them into the `cli_args` and iterate over them and output all the returned data.

Comment: I hope the above makes sense?

Comment: I think I understood what you mean, you get a list of clusters after calling **get_aks_clusters** and a list of rgs after calling **get_aks_rg**, then you call **get_aks_k8s_ver** passing a list of clusters and a list of rgs as arguments, you want to call az for each pair? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct but please bear in mind that the `get_aks_k8s_ver` will need to loop and go through the list of the clusters and return the outputs.

Comment: I'm just not sure how I would loop through the `cli_arg` with the lists from the other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide an example of clusters and rgs lists, it'd be easier, so I'm gonna write a solution based on my own interpretation, if you edit your question, I'll modify my solution accordingly.

```py
def get_aks_k8s_ver(clusters, rgs):
    versions = []
    for rg, cluster in zip(clusters, rgs):
        cli_args = (
            "aks",
            "get-upgrades",
            "-g",
            rg,
            "-n",
            cluster,
            "--query",
            "controlPlaneProfile.kubernetesVersion",
            "-o",
            "json"
        )
        version = az(cli_args, suppress_stdout=False)
        versions.append(version)
    return versions

# clusters = ['cluster1', 'cluster2', ..., 'clusterN']
clusters = get_aks_clusters()
# rgs = ['rg1', 'rg2', ..., 'rgN']
rgs = get_aks_rgs()

# versions = ['version1', 'version2', ..., 'versionN']
versions = get_aks_k8s_ver(clusters, rgs)
```

Comment: Morning/Afternoon,

So I tried the above but I kept getting following error:

`TypeError: get_aks_k8s_ver(clusters, rgs) missing 1 required positional argument: rgs`

I then changed the versions call to the following and it seemed to work:

`versions = get_aks_k8s_ver(self="", rgs=ClusterInfo().get_aks_rg(), clusters=ClusterInfo().get_aks_clusters())`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope the edit of the versions call was ok and pythonic :)

Comment: You're welcome. Did you have the function inside a **class**? I'm asking because of the self argument.

Comment: I had added the class after I posted this, so yes :D